# Why Java 8 CompletableFuture thenCompose generates different exception depending on the order of completion?

Tags: java, java-8, future

I have encountered strange behavior of Java 8 CompletableFuture thenCompose method. I have two tests that differ only in order of execution. Both tests simulate failure in the CompletableFuture generated in thenCompose.

```
@Test
public void completedAfter() {
    CompletableFuture<String> future1 = new CompletableFuture<>();
    CompletableFuture<String> future2 = new CompletableFuture<>();

    future1.thenCompose(x -> future2).whenComplete((r, e) -> System.out.println("After: " + e));

    future1.complete("value");
    future2.completeExceptionally(new RuntimeException());
}

@Test
public void completedBefore() {
    CompletableFuture<String> future1 = new CompletableFuture<>();
    CompletableFuture<String> future2 = new CompletableFuture<>();

    future1.complete("value");
    future2.completeExceptionally(new RuntimeException());

    future1.thenCompose(x -> future2).whenComplete((r, e) -> System.out.println("Before: " +e));
}
```

The output is:

```
After: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.RuntimeException
Before: java.lang.RuntimeException
```

The question is, why is the exception wrapped in `CompletionException` in one case but not in the other?

**Update: [Here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8068432) is related bug report. It has been marked and resolved as a bug in JDK.**

Comment: Have you looked at Guava's ListenableFuture?  If you are not locked into the framework, I suggest using Guava's implementation.  In my totally opinionated view, it is feature complete and much easier to use.  Disclamer, I am in no way affiliated with Google.

Comment: There has been a lot of traffic on Completablefuture on the concurrency interest list. The November lists might be of interest to you: http://cs.oswego.edu/pipermail/concurrency-interest/2014-November/subject.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a bug in the jdk library.

In the "After" case, `.thenCompose` adds a `ThenCopy` completion node to the target future, whose execution is later triggered by `.completeExceptionally`. The completion node's `run` method finds the exception on the  future, and calls `.internalComplete` on the destination, that wraps all exceptions into `CompletionException`.
See [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.java#1466) how the node is created, and [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.java#1333) for where the wrapping happens.

Now, in the `Before` case, the code path is completely different. Because the future is already completed, `.thenCompose` does not create additional nodes, but [invokes](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.java#1996) the callback right away, and simply returns an (already completed second future), on which you then call `.whenComplete`, which, again, does not bother to create a new completion node, but simply [invokes the callback](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.java#2048) right away, giving it the original exception from the second future.

Boy, looking at this code, there are so many examples I want to show to my students of what they should never do ...

Comment: Why a bug? Does the behavior violate any contracts?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik It's quite unclear. This has to do with dependent `CompletionStage`s. _Dependencies on a single stage are arranged using methods with prefix `then`._ and _if a stage's computation terminates abruptly with an (unchecked) exception or error, then all dependent stages requiring its completion complete exceptionally as well, with a `CompletionException` holding the exception as its cause._

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I did not see it mentioned explicitly anywhere that all exceptions, thrown by the future will be wrapped into a `CompletableException`, but I doubt the intent is that they are *sometimes* wrapped, and sometimes are not, depending on the ... what? cpu speed? I mean, this behavior is non-deterministic. Perhaps, a "bug" was too strong of a word. Let's call it "undesired feature"?

Comment: Thanks, I will file a bug and we will see how Oracle reacts.